# Managing Reshape correctly to build RNN from a previous CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I am currently trying to build a CRNN with Keras. When I try to reshape the input size, I had some trouble finding the correct dimension for my LSTM. After some debugging, I found a field in my **model** object called **output_shape** whose value was (3,1,244) and I tried to pass it as a 2D array with (3,224). Everything worked fine, but did I do correctly? What is the math behind this and what can I do next time to discover this size without debugging?

```
def CRNN(blockSize, blockCount, inputShape, trainGen, testGen, epochs):

model = Sequential()

# Conv Layer
channels = 32
for i in range(blockCount):
    for j in range(blockSize):
        if (i, j) == (0, 0):
            conv = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                          input_shape=inputShape, padding='same')
        else:
            conv = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same')
        model.add(conv)
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.15))
        if j == blockSize - 2:
            channels += 32
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.15))

# Feature aggregation across time
model.add(Reshape((3, 224)))

# LSTM layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200), merge_mode='ave'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Linear classifier
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy']) # F1?


model.fit_generator(trainGen,
                    validation_data=testGen, steps_per_epoch = trainGen.x.size // 20,
                    validation_steps = testGen.x.size // 20,
                    epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
return model

# Function call
model = CRNN(4, 6, (140, 33, 1), trainGen, testGen, 1)
```